# Sub-namespaces for exceptions

Tags: zend-framework, namespaces, zend-framework2, symfony

In PHP, I often see that exceptions are often isolated in a sub namespace.

And this is happening in popular frameworks.

For example:

1) **Symfony 2, Symfony 3:**

- namespace Symfony\Component\Console\Exception;
- namespace Symfony\Component\Config\Exception;
- namespace Symfony\Component\Form\Exception;
- etc...

This is described even in the [Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html):

> Exception classes should be stored in an Exception sub-namespace.

2) **Zend Framework 2**:

- namespace Zend\Form\Exception;
- namespace Zend\Ldap\Exception;
- namespace Zend\Di\Exception;
- etc...

3) **PHP-DI**:

- namespace DI\Definition\Exception;

A few years ago I followed this practice(sub-namespaces for exceptions).
I'm not even thinking about this decision as Symfony, Zend - industry leaders.
I just followed suit.

But now I'm thinking about this decision, and it seems it is not right to me.

Now it seems to me that the exception should be in the same namespace as the class that causes it.

What do you think about this? Which of these is better(and why)?

- Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException

OR

- Symfony\Component\Console\CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

According to PSR-0 it is the best way to store exceptions.

It is here because you can have more than 10 Exception classes for different cases according to one class. And storing them in one folder with many other classes can mess up developers.

Imagine that you have folder with 10 classes that implements business logic and 100 Exception classes for them. Is it will be easy for you to find some specific class?

Another problem: you can have two exceptions with the same name but related to different issues: e.g. you can create `NotFoundException` telling that controller needs to return `404` HTTP status code but it can also telling that some file has not been found.

Comment: 1) PSR-0 does not contain such information. Other PSR not contain too. 2) PSR-3 default exception: Psr\Log\InvalidArgumentException 3) 10 classes and 100 exceptions - This case is too far-fetched.

Comment: PSR-0 states "Each namespace separator is converted to a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR when loading from the file system.". It means that all files with one namespace have to be located at one folder.

Comment: You do not understand the issue. The issue is that better: Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException or Symfony\Component\Console\CommandNotFoundException. And why.

Comment: You do not understand my answer. I wrote that in second case all your exceptions will be located at one folder according PSR-0. And so you will have very specific names for all exceptions and many files in one folder. It is not convenient for developers to find one class in many files. Really, try to find one concrete class from hundred classes (files).